# Getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.createCriteriaUpdate

Tags: hibernate, maven, jpa, nosuchmethoderror, jpa-2.1

My project on is originally on JPA 2.0 and I'm trying to update to JPA 2.1. I'm trying to use the 'CriteriaUpdate' which uses JPA 2.1. I added the hibernate-jpa-2.1-api to my maven pom.xml and I have the javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaUpdate library in the folder. However, I'm getting the the following error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.createCriteriaUpdate(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljavax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaUpdate;
at com.cfins.esbConsole.dao.AuthenticationDao.changeUsrPaswrd(AuthenticationDao.java:177)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.invokeProceed(EJSContainer.java:5730)
at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InvocationContextImpl.proceed(InvocationContextImpl.java:568)
at org.apache.webbeans.ejb.common.interceptor.OpenWebBeansEjbInterceptor.callInterceptorsAndDecorators(OpenWebBeansEjbInterceptor.java:526)
at org.apache.webbeans.ejb.common.interceptor.OpenWebBeansEjbInterceptor.callToOwbInterceptors(OpenWebBeansEjbInterceptor.java:200)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InterceptorProxy.invokeInterceptor(InterceptorProxy.java:227)
at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InvocationContextImpl.proceed(InvocationContextImpl.java:548)
at org.apache.webbeans.ejb.WSEJBInterceptor.callToOwbInterceptors(WSEJBInterceptor.java:136)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InterceptorProxy.invokeInterceptor(InterceptorProxy.java:227)
at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InvocationContextImpl.proceed(InvocationContextImpl.java:548)
at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InvocationContextImpl.doAroundInvoke(InvocationContextImpl.java:229)
at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.invoke(EJSContainer.java:5621)
... 47 more
```

These the dependencies I'm using

```
      <!-- JPA -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
 <!-- For date time api  -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
      <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>            

      <!-- Optional, but highly recommended. -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
         <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
         <version>5.10</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
         <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
      </dependency>

<!-- for session  -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
    <artifactId>ejb-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
</dependency>

 <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
    <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>


      <!-- Needed on JBoss AS as EL is out of date -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
         <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
         <scope>runtime</scope>
         <!-- FIXME this version should be in the Weld API BOM -->
         <version>2.1.2-b04</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
```

I've read other post on similar issues and nothing worked for me such as updating to Java ee 7 and deleting the old hibernate jpa jars. What is the problem?

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer, since it answers the question you posted

Answer (score 0):

You have JPA API 2.0 jar (or earlier) in the CLASSPATH somewhere. It's all well and good putting JPA API 2.1 in the CLASSPATH but you need to remove the existing jar as well

Answer (score 0):

You must having multiple Jpa jars.

Answer (score 0):

Set in project facets JPA versión 2.1